# AppEngine application can't make cookies once online but works fine on localhost -- is this right?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

My problem is the following: i'm trying to make a sort of forum, for which i want to authenticate users through a simple cookie-session pattern. for this i am using the session utility from the book Using App Engine. My problem is, while thiis works just fine when i try it on local host, with multiple users logged in, i can´t manage to make it work once online. 
The problem is the cookie is just not created. Has anyone seen something like this before? sorry if i am missing something obvious im just starting using app engine

UPDATED
my code to set the cookie is like this,

```
        self.sid = str(random.random())[5:]+str(random.random())[5:]
        self.key = "session-" + self.sid
        logging.info("Creating session "+self.key);
        self.session = dict()
        memcache.add(self.key, self.session, 3600)
        self.cookie[COOKIE_NAME] = self.sid
        self.cookie[COOKIE_NAME]['path'] = "/"
        self.cookie[COOKIE_NAME]["domain"] = "example.appspot.com"
        # Send the Cookie header to the browser
        print self.cookie
```

Comment: I don't know much about app engine, and your question may well benefit from some more details, bit one thing I would suggest: is your program setting the correct domain for the cookie. On your local machine, setting no domain works fine, but on a website a browser will expect the correct domain before setting a cookie.

Comment: Are you setting the `Secure` property of your cookie when it's a https:// URL? If not, try setting it. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Secure_cookie

Comment: You should definitely use an existing session library, rather than inventing your own. If you're using webapp, consider switching to Python 2.7 and webapp2, which has built in session support.

Comment: thanks i didn't know webapp2 even existed this has helped me a lot

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at https://github.com/dound/gae-sessions ? I found it to be very simple to get up and running and does a lot of the dirty work for you.

Answer (score 0):

I have used https://github.com/dound/gae-sessions in a couple of my projects. Works like a charm!